# Can't get item two in loop

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to iterate through all open documents in Photoshop to grab the height and width of each image.

For whatever reason, I get an error the second time through the loop saying it can't get the second item. (Error on line 5)

Code:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop 2020"
    set currentDocs to documents
    set myList to {}
    repeat with n from 1 to count of currentDocs
        set currentDoc to current document of item n
        tell currentDoc
            set theDimensions to bounds of current layer
            set theWidth to item 3 of theDimensions
            set theHeight to item 4 of theDimensions
            set theDimensions to theWidth & theHeight
            set end of myList to theDimensions
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the item `n` of `currentDocs`

```
set currentDoc to item n of currentDocs
```

Or use the `repeat with ... in ...` syntax

```
repeat with currentDoc in currentDocs
   tell currentDoc ...
```